# Mysql - How to get ranking of choice base on table value

Tags: mysql, database

I have many users that can select their choice from rank 1-4.
The table look like this:

> username rank1  rank2  rank3  rank4
>   Perter   Apple  Orange Grape  Melon
>   Adam     Orange Melon  Apple  Grape
>   James    Melon  Grape  Orange Apple

How do I get a table like this in php mysql

> username   Apple  Orange  Grape Melon
>   Peter      1st-choice 2nd-choice 3rd-choice 4th-choice
>   Adam       3rd-choice 1st-choice 4th-choice 2nd-choice
>   Jame       4th-choice 3rd-choice 2nd-choice 1st-choice

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to count grades and are grades in letter form?

Comment: Sorry for the confuse, I edited my example.